# Fresh install of my rails project causes SQLite3::SQLException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I wanted to test my project runs correctly on a fresh install.

```
https://github.com/Nims09/ts_test_ui
```

For a normal new project, I clone it then do:

```
git clone https://github.com/Nims09/ts_test_ui

bundle install

rake db:migrate

rails server
```

And it should run, however `rake db:migrate` Gives me a:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: simulations: SELECT  "simulations".* FROM "simulations"  ORDER BY "simulations"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
```

Can anyone help me solve why this is happening? Am I using the correct steps? Have I committed a DB file I shouldn't have?

Full log:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: simulations: SELECT  "simulations".* FROM "simulations"  ORDER BY "simulations"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:296:in `block in exec_query'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:293:in `exec_query'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:347:in `select'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:32:in `select_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:70:in `select_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in `find_by_sql'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:638:in `exec_queries'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:514:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:243:in `to_a'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:523:in `find_last'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:172:in `last'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `last'
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/test5/ts_test_ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:18:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:18:in `factory'
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/test5/ts_test_ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:7:in `define'
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/test5/ts_test_ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in find_definitions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `block in find_definitions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `find_definitions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl_rails-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb:21:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/test5/ts_test_ui/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: simulations
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:296:in `block in exec_query'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:293:in `exec_query'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:347:in `select'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:32:in `select_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:70:in `select_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in `find_by_sql'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:638:in `exec_queries'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:514:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:243:in `to_a'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:523:in `find_last'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:172:in `last'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `last'
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/test5/ts_test_ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:18:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:18:in `factory'
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/test5/ts_test_ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:7:in `define'
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/test5/ts_test_ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in find_definitions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `block in find_definitions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `find_definitions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl_rails-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb:21:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/test5/ts_test_ui/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
```

m1:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => "", limit: 96
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => "", limit: 60

      t.timestamps

      t.index :email, unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

m2

```
class CreateSimulations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # Needs the hash column worked out before this is run 
    create_table :simulations do |t|
        t.integer :x_size
        t.integer :y_size
        t.string :verdict
        t.string :arrangement 
    end

    add_reference :simulations, :user, index: true    
  end
end
```

m3

```
class RemoveVerdictFromSimulation < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :simulations, :verdict, :string
  end
end
```

m4

```
class AddOpinionToSimulations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :simulations, :opinion, :string
  end
end
```

m5

```
class AddIdentifierToSimulations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :simulations, :identifier, :string
  end
end
```

Development.log:

```
  [1m[36mSimulation Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "simulations".* FROM "simulations"  ORDER BY "simulations"."id" DESC LIMIT 1[0m
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: simulations: SELECT  "simulations".* FROM "simulations"  ORDER BY "simulations"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
```

From Command line:

```
Nathaniels-MacBook-Pro:ts_test_ui nathanielmots$ rake db:drop
Nathaniels-MacBook-Pro:ts_test_ui nathanielmots$ rake db:create
Nathaniels-MacBook-Pro:ts_test_ui nathanielmots$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: simulations: SELECT  "simulations".* FROM "simulations"  ORDER BY "simulations"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:296:in `block in exec_query'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:293:in `exec_query'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:347:in `select'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:32:in `select_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:70:in `select_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in `find_by_sql'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:638:in `exec_queries'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:514:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:243:in `to_a'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:523:in `find_last'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:172:in `last'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `last'
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/test6/ts_test_ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:18:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:18:in `factory'
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/test6/ts_test_ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:7:in `define'
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/test6/ts_test_ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in find_definitions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `block in find_definitions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `find_definitions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl_rails-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb:21:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/test6/ts_test_ui/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: simulations
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:296:in `block in exec_query'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:293:in `exec_query'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:347:in `select'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:32:in `select_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:70:in `select_all'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:39:in `find_by_sql'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:638:in `exec_queries'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:514:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:243:in `to_a'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:523:in `find_last'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:172:in `last'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `last'
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/test6/ts_test_ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:18:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:18:in `factory'
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/test6/ts_test_ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:7:in `define'
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/test6/ts_test_ui/spec/factories/simulations.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in find_definitions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:19:in `block in find_definitions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/find_definitions.rb:15:in `find_definitions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl_rails-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl_rails/railtie.rb:21:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:62:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/Users/nathanielmots/Documents/Development/ThemisSolutions/test6/ts_test_ui/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: That SQL is equivalent to `Simulation.first`, which is evidently running before the simulations table is created. Could you be referring to `Simulation.first` in a model or initializer?

Comment: I changed my setup steps to this: clone, bundle install, `rake db:schema:load ` and then rails server, and this works. I assume this is the correct way to setup a new project.

Comment: No, it is not the correct way. You just loaded the full schema, and your table appeared. The way you want to start your project from scratch is to drop your database (in case you had it from before), recreate it, and then run migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the stacktrace, it looks like it might be related to the `factory_girl_rails` gem. The [simulations.rb](https://github.com/Nims09/ts_test_ui/blob/2a387c0c09847eacc4a7bf484cfbb3e88834d63a/spec/factories/simulations.rb) file in the repository seems to suggest the same, as it would produce the SQL in your error.

Change this line in your Gemfile:

`gem 'factory_girl_rails'`

To this:

`gem 'factory_girl_rails', :require => false`

And add this to [spec_helper.rb](https://github.com/Nims09/ts_test_ui/blob/2a387c0c09847eacc4a7bf484cfbb3e88834d63a/spec/spec_helper.rb):

`require 'factory_girl_rails'`

Then run `bundle install`.  After that, try running the migration again.

Comment: This works true, when requiring false, the migrations run correctly, however even with adding the the erquire to the spec helper, my rspec fails.

Comment: I can okay this answer but how can I fix my tests now?

Comment: This is the error I recieve when running rspec  `Nathaniels-MacBook-Pro:ts_test_ui nathanielmots$ rspec
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:100:in `require': unable to find a version of 'railties' to activate (Gem::LoadError)`

Comment: Is that after running bundle install?

Comment: Yes its from running rspec after I have done a bundle install

Comment: Sounds like railties isn't installed.  What's the output of `gem list | grep railties`?

Comment: `Nathaniels-MacBook-Pro:ts_test_ui nathanielmots$ gem list | grep railties
railties (4.2.1, 4.0.0)`

Comment: Odd.  Not sure if I can help with that one.  Maybe try uninstalling your current versions, and reinstalling one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running "rake db:migrate" right away, reset your current database:

rake db:drop

rake db:create

rake db:migrate

Most likely your migrations table is out of sync.

That is what I need:

```
     ➤ rake db:migrate
    == 20150717093728 CreateInvitees: migrating ===================================
    -- create_table(:invitees)
       -> 0.0936s
    == 20150717093728 CreateInvitees: migrated (0.0938s) ==========================
```

The output of all the commands I mentioned **from command line**

Comment: Right, but it just means that something is wrong with your migrations. Add to your question the full log of you commands, and we can find out what it is. In other words, if someone else would run your project from scratch, she would get the same errors.

Comment: No, i did not mean that. I could see your migrations on my own in https://github.com/Nims09/ts_test_ui. What I need is the full output, of running 'rake db:drop' (which should be empty), 'rake db:create' (which also should be empty), and the full log after running your 'rake db:migrate' at the end, with all the tables that were created and which one failed. I don't need the full error stack that you posted. I need to know what was before it.

Comment: I added the development.log, its short and only contains the original error. Any idea where this might be going wrong?

Comment: I got the log file because I thought there might be more there. The full log is the dump I get when running the `rake db:migrate` in command line

Comment: I added what I need to my answer.

Comment: Ok, at least now I can see that there is nothing wrong with your migrations, and the answer from Sculper most likely will help.

Comment: It proves a solution for solving the migrations error but now my tests are having problems, as I mentioned in a comment on his answer

Comment: Right, but it is not part of your question. However, why would someone do something like this ( f.id (Simulation.last.nil? ? 1 : Simulation.last.id + 1) )? You don't need to generate ids in Factory Girls.

Comment: I was getting 'non unique' problems when running my tests so I added that field to always generate unique identifiers when my tests ran

Comment: Riiiight, so you fixed it in the way you saw fits. I c... Programming is not about fixing, it is about making things the right way, and to make things the right way you have to learn first, and not just by trials and errors.

Comment: Absolutely, I went looking for a correct solution and found this on Stackoverflow, I figured this was a reasonable solution and was not aware that this was not the correct way. Im happy to find the right way to do it but it's not always clear, what would be the right way of going about it?

Comment: you should learn about this gem https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner and how to use it in your tests. It helps you cleanup after each test (more or less), so each test starts from clean database, and there will be no unique id problems. Please read about testing some more.